# Dropzonejs - rename file before upload

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, dropzone.js

I have dropzone set-up and working with my AWS S3 account. However I want to be able to rename the file before it is sent to S3 (append with timestamp for example) so that a file uploaded with the same name as an existing file will not get overwritten. I've tried to catch this at the sending event and to update the file name at this point but without success:

```
this.on("sending", function(file) {
  file.name = 'my-new-prefix-' + file.name;
});
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong or why this isn't working?

Also have raised this earlier at - https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/345

Comment: file.name is a property of the File object, and its read-only! see: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/File

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I currently use [FromData() - Dropzone.js](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/src/dropzone.coffee#L973) which allows you to send custom data.

```
// with options.params = true;

this.on("sending", function(file) {
  formData.append("custom", "my-new-prefix-" + file.name);
});
```

I know this is not exactly what is your question, it is only a temporary solution without modifying the source code

You can also pass object directly in options:

```
el.dropzone({
  params: {
    data: "data"
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but how does this update the file name getting posted to S3?

Comment: During your image process before upload to S3, you can handle custom params and so rename your file

Comment: Just got back to look at this and this works perfect.  Cheers.

Comment: @PierreBroucz Can you please tell me in detail how to change file name before uploading using with dropzone.js. Check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24859005/3113858

Comment: @PierreBroucz Can you elaborate that `params` one as I want to use that instead of `formData` because that gives `undefined` error.