# Dropzone.js - How to change file name before uploading to folder

Tags: jquery, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I am using [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) script for uploading images with drag & drop, but now I'm looking for a solution for how to add current timestamps with file name before uploading to the server folder, because I am not able to upload the same image if the file already exists in the folder.

I have also referred below stackoverflow link but I'm confused where to implement this.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23805488/3113858
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19432731/3113858

Here is [dropzone.js script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enyo/dropzone/master/downloads/dropzone.js) for reference

Comment: Hello, Did you find any solution for this issue. if yes then could you please share it. if possible with an example code. thank you

Comment: @JasbirBhinder Not found any solution.

Comment: Ok. And are you using dropzone with asp.net. I am trying to call webmethod from dropzone url but it is not working. Dropzone Returning html response back page.

Comment: I have used dropzone with PHP.

Comment: you can change the name on server-side and return it after success on upload, and use jquery trick to replace the old name with new returned name

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to my one, it is much simpler and keeps the rename on the client side. :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please check following code I have implemented using PHP.

Use Following code in your **index file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
            var fileList = new Array;
            var i =0;
            $("#some-dropzone").dropzone({
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                init: function() {

                    // Hack: Add the dropzone class to the element
                    $(this.element).addClass("dropzone");

                    this.on("success", function(file, serverFileName) {
                        fileList[i] = {"serverFileName" : serverFileName, "fileName" : file.name,"fileId" : i };
                        //console.log(fileList);
                        i++;

                    });
                    this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
                        var rmvFile = "";
                        for(f=0;f<fileList.length;f++){

                            if(fileList[f].fileName == file.name)
                            {
                                rmvFile = fileList[f].serverFileName;

                            }

                        }

                        if (rmvFile){
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "http://localhost/dropzone/sample/delete_temp_files.php",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: { "fileList" : rmvFile }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                },
                url: "http://localhost/dropzone/sample/upload.php"
            });

        });
```

**Upload.php**

```
<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  // Store directory separator (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) to a simple variable. This is just a personal preference as we hate to type long variable name.
$storeFolder = 'uploads';   // Declare a variable for destination folder.
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          // If file is sent to the page, store the file object to a temporary variable.
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  // Create the absolute path of the destination folder.
    // Adding timestamp with image's name so that files with same name can be uploaded easily.
    $date = new DateTime();
    $newFileName = $date->getTimestamp().$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile =  $targetPath.$newFileName;  // Create the absolute path of the uploaded file destination.
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); // Move uploaded file to destination.

    echo $newFileName;
}
?>
```

**delete_temp_files.php**

```
<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  // Store directory separator (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) to a simple variable. This is just a personal preference as we hate to type long variable name.
$storeFolder = 'uploads'; 

$fileList = $_POST['fileList'];
$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;


if(isset($fileList)){
    unlink($targetPath.$fileList);
}

?>
```

Hope this will be helpful for uploading images using ajax and delete using ajax :)

I have found from following references:

[Dropzone.js- How to delete files from server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452662/dropzone-js-how-to-delete-files-from-server/17457380#17457380)
[Dropzone.js remove button with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400470/dropzone-js-remove-button-with-php/17427379#17427379)

Also add following code in your dropzone.js file after line #1110 for preventing user to upload duplicate files with same name :)

```
Dropzone.prototype.addFile = function(file) {
    if (this.files.length) {
        var _i, _len;
        for (_i = 0, _len = this.files.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            if(this.files[_i].name === file.name && this.files[_i].size === file.size) {
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Reference Link: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/2993843-dropzone-did-not-check-the-duplicate-file-on-addfile?utm_campaign=plugin&utm_content=tracker%2F283989&utm_medium=issues&utm_source=github

Comment: @Mr.Happy Where is it adding timestamp? My requirement is to rename file before upload and also show new renamed file name in preview.

Answer (score 24):

To prefix the filename with a timestamp each time before upload, you have two options depending on you version of DropzoneJS.

The newer versions of **DropzoneJS 5.1+** does have a `renameFile` function that is used as followed:

```
    ...
    renameFile: function (file) {
        return new Date().getTime() + '_' + file.name;
    }
    ...
```

---

In **older versions** v4.3 - v5.1 this is done a little bit different.

In this versions there is a `renameFilename` option, this is used like this:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropzone").dropzone({
        renameFilename: function (filename) {
            return new Date().getTime() + '_' + filename;
        }
    });
});
```

Happy coding,
Kalasch

Comment: Note that this also appears to rename the filename on init for preloaded images from your server as well. @Kalaschni - do you know if there's a way to only implement a file rename on upload?

Comment: @wazdev you could examine the filename passed to the callback... if it already appears to be renamed, return it untouched.  :|

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! it is so much simpler and gets the job done on the client side.

Comment: @ParikTiwari I too have done the same. But file.name is not getting modified to new name. Here is my code. Can someone spot any problems?

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var UPLOAD_URL = decodeURIComponent('<%=storageUrl%>');
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#upload-widget", { url: UPLOAD_URL,
        paramName: 'files[]',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: 'application/pdf',
        renameFile: function (file) {
            file.name = 'some-random-name';
        }

   });

Comment: @prem911: which version of Dropzone do you use?

Comment: @Kalaschni I m using the latest version 5.4. The surprising thing is that the deprecated API renameFilename worked. However, renameFile is still not working. This is going against the spirit of the documentation. I will raise a defect in github page

Comment: For anyone struggling with version 5.1+ the code here is incorrect. It's needs to be: `renameFile: function (file) {
        return new Date().getTime() + '_' + file.name;
    }`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Max, I have changed my answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just used the standard php file rename.

```html
$targetFile =  $targetPath . $_FILES['file']['name']; //the original upload
$newfilename = "somename" . $variable . ".jpg"; //a new filename string

rename($targetFile , $new); //rename at the end of the function
```

This worked well for me and was pretty simple to implement. The .jpg extension is probably not recommended to hard code but in my scenario im only getting jpg file types.