# Dropzone (with file renaming) is working. I need to populate a js form using PHPexcel or sheetsJS. Can't seem to get queuecomplete to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

Here is what I did to get the file renaming working:
[Dropzone.js - How to change file name before uploading to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859005/dropzone-js-how-to-change-file-name-before-uploading-to-folder)

**From index.php:**

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        var fileList = new Array;
        var i =0;
        $("#some-dropzone").dropzone({
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            init: function() {

                // Hack: Add the dropzone class to the element
                $(this.element).addClass("dropzone");

                this.on("success", function(file, serverFileName) {
                    fileList[i] = {"serverFileName" : serverFileName, "fileName" : file.name,"fileId" : i };
                    //console.log(fileList);
                    i++;

                });
                this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
                    var rmvFile = "";
                    for(f=0;f<fileList.length;f++){

                        if(fileList[f].fileName == file.name)
                        {
                            rmvFile = fileList[f].serverFileName;

                        }

                    }

                    if (rmvFile){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "http://localhost/dropzone/sample/delete_temp_files.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { "fileList" : rmvFile }
                        });
                    }
                });

            },
            url: "http://localhost/dropzone/sample/upload.php"
        });

    });
```

**From upload.php:**

```
            <?php
            $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  // Store directory separator (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) to a simple variable. This is just a personal preference as we hate to type long variable name.
            $storeFolder = 'uploads';   // Declare a variable for destination folder.
            if (!empty($_FILES)) {

                $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          // If file is sent to the page, store the file object to a temporary variable.
                $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  // Create the absolute path of the destination folder.
                // Adding timestamp with image's name so that files with same name can be uploaded easily.
                $date = new DateTime();
                $newFileName = $date->getTimestamp().$_FILES['file']['name'];
                $targetFile =  $targetPath.$newFileName;  // Create the absolute path of the uploaded file destination.
                move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); // Move uploaded file to destination.

                echo $newFileName;
            }
            ?>
```

**New file delete_tmp_files.php:**

```
            <?php
            $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  // Store directory separator (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) to a simple variable. This is just a personal preference as we hate to type long variable name.
            $storeFolder = 'uploads'; 

            $fileList = $_POST['fileList'];
            $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;


            if(isset($fileList)){
                unlink($targetPath.$fileList);
            }

            ?>
```

Here I need dropzone to call PHPExcel or sheetJS.  I have sheetJS parsing to CSV in a static page using ajax here:

```
            <html>
            <head>

            <title>AJAX XLS TEST</title>

            </head>

            <body>
            <br/><div id="fileurl"></div>
            <pre id="out"></pre>
            <br />

            <script src="js/iemagic.js"></script>
            <script src="js/shim.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jszip.js"></script>
            <script src="js/xlsx.js"></script>
            <script>
            function to_csv(workbook) {
                var result = [];
                workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                    var csv = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                    if(csv.length > 0){
                        result.push("SHEET: " + sheetName);
                        result.push("");
                        result.push(csv);
                    }
                });
                return result.join("\n");
            }

            function process_wb(wb) {
                var output = to_csv(wb);
                if(out.innerText === undefined) out.textContent = output;
                else out.innerText = output;
                if(typeof console !== 'undefined') console.log("output", new Date());
            }

            var url = "uploads/fw.xls";

            var oReq;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            else if(window.ActiveXObject) oReq = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
            else throw "XHR unavailable for your browser";

            document.getElementById('fileurl').innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Download file</a>';

            oReq.open("GET", url, true);

            if(typeof Uint8Array !== 'undefined') {
                oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
                oReq.onload = function(e) {
                    if(typeof console !== 'undefined') console.log("onload", new Date());
                    var arraybuffer = oReq.response;
                    var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
                    var arr = new Array();
                    for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
                    var wb = XLSX.read(arr.join(""), {type:"binary"});
                    process_wb(wb);
                };
            } else {
                oReq.setRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "x-user-defined");  
                oReq.onreadystatechange = function() { if(oReq.readyState == 4 && oReq.status == 200) {
                    var ff = convertResponseBodyToText(oReq.responseBody);
                    if(typeof console !== 'undefined') console.log("onload", new Date());
                    var wb = XLSX.read(ff, {type:"binary"});
                    process_wb(wb);
                } };
            }

            oReq.send();

            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36810333-1']);
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                (function() {
                    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                })();
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Question 1:  How do I get dropzone to call this ajax csv output?  A.  There is "queuecomplete" but where to put the quecomplete code (body? head? index.php? Upload.php?    Another option would be using PHPexcel (below) but again not sure how to get dropzone to call it after renaming is done:

```
            | Excel To Array
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Helper function to convert excel sheet to key value array
            | Input: path to excel file, set wether excel first row are headers
            | Dependencies: PHPExcel.php include needed
            */
                    $filePath = "uploads/fw.xls";

            function excelToArray($filePath, $header=true){
                    //Create excel reader after determining the file type
                    $inputFileName = $filePath;
                    /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
                    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
                    /**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
                    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
                    /** Set read type to read cell data onl **/
                    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
                    /**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
                    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
                    //Get worksheet and built array with first row as header
                    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
                    //excel with first row header, use header as key
                    if($header){<SNIP>
```

I really think PHPexcel would be much easier when it comes to culling out specific data from the xls as I only need specific fields to populate the following javascript form, but again, where do I put the PHPexcel script?  Do I use queuecomplete to call the file?  I think if I use queuecomplete and reference phpexcel_parse.php I could get it going from there but I just can't seem to get dropzone to do something with the file after uploading and renaming is complete.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Side note, I could eliminate the file renaming completely, we really don't have a business need for it right away.